Number of initial zeros after the decimal point of $\frac{1}{20^{20}}$

The decimal representation of $\frac{1}{20^{20}}$ has a string of ZEROs after the decimal point followed by a 9 and then several more digits. How many ZEROs are there in the initial string of ZEROs after the decimal point?

If we multiply numerator and denominator by $5^{20},$ we get $\frac{5^{20}}{{100}^{20}}$. So that is $\frac{5^{20}}{{10}^{40}}$. So ${10}^{40}$ in the denominator will give $39$ ZEROs after the decimal. I am unable to figure out how many of those ZEROs will be cancelled out by $5^{20}$.

$~\dfrac{1}{n} ~: ~n \in \Bbb{Z^+}~$ will have a string of exactly $~k~$ 0's, immediately after the decimal point, if and only if $~10^k < n \leq 10^{k+1} ~: ~k \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$
Note that $~\log_{10} ~2 \approx 0.301.$  Therefore,
$$20^{20} = 10^{20} \times 2^{20} \approx 10^{20} \times 10^{6.02} = 10^{26.02}.$$
Therefore, the decimal expression of the fraction will start with $~26~$ 0's.

Using $2^{10} = 1024 \;\to\; 2^{20} = (1024)^2 \approx 1.05\times 10^6$ then, for some $0 \lt x \lt .1$, we get
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{20^{20}} & = \frac{1}{2^{20}\times 10^{20}} \\
& \approx \frac{1}{(1.05\times 10^6)\times 10^{20}} \\
& = \frac{1}{1.05}\times 10^{-26} \\
& = (.9 + x)\times 10^{-26}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$
For any integer $n \ge 0$, note that $.9\times 10^{-n}$ has a decimal point, $n$ zeros, and then a $9$. Thus, the decimal representation of $\frac{1}{20^{20}}$ has an initial $26$ zeros after the decimal point.
